# upload files with special characters onto mediawiki on wampserver

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters, mediawiki, wampserver

I try to upload a file onto my locale mediawiki on WAMP Server with Special Characters in the name (for example ö,ü,ä), but I only get this error message:

```
This wiki does not support filenames with special characters.
```

My Configuration:

- Wampserver 2.2
- MySQL: 5.5.24
- PHP: 5.2.9-2
- Apache: 2.2.22
- Mediawiki 1.19.2

I've already tried to set the default charset in php.ini, my.ini, httpd.conf and LocalSettings.php to utf-8, but this have effect. Is there a way that I can upload files with special characters in the name? I've already spent days with this issue, would be great if someone could give me some hints.

Answer (score 1):

That's an [issue with the MediaWiki software](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1780), not your configuration.

Comment: And what can i do to upload files with special characters in the name?

Comment: Looking at the bug report (and having a quick scan through the source code) I don't think you can. Here's the patch they created to prevent special characters on Windows: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:Code/MediaWiki/88165

Comment: I solved the problem so: I've installed a linux (Ubuntu in my case) in a Vbox and create a Server on it.(How to: http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts-lamp) Then I was able to upload files with filenames with special characters. I think it is possible to import the DB from the LAMP to WAMP, but I don't tested it.